How to find the image field of a Gaussian beam impinging on a positive lens? I am trying to calculate the impulse response and find the image field

How to get the image field for the setup in the following question , where a Gaussian beam is incident on a positive lens with focal length f z0 and z1 are the object and image distance? Can anyone help me with the approach?

Have you learned how to do ray propagation using the ABCD matrix?
